# PHP will not execute a line of code unless you refresh the page twice

Tags: php, drupal, iframe, cookies

I am trying to make one website have both Wix and a standalone desktop version. However I'm running into a problem with the Wix version when this website is loaded into a Wix iFrame.

when the IF statement is true, the user should automatically be redirected, meaning if you're visiting this website within a Wix iFrame that line of code starting with "header" must be executed because the IF statement is returning true.

```
 if(isset($_GET[ 'instance' ], $_GET[ 'siteUrl' ], $_GET['locale']))
{       
    $value = 1;
    setcookie("IsWixUser", $value, time()+3600);
    header('Location: app.php?show=social_manager');
}
else
{
    $value = -1;
    setcookie("IsWixUser", $value, time()+3600);
}
```

This is not the case when you're loading my website for the first time with Wix starting with no cookies at all. Using firebug I can check the resources and see that the cookie "IsWixUser" has been properly executed to hold a $value of 1, so the setcookie() works perfectly the first time, but the browser just decides to skip the header() function and doesn't execute that at all.

The header() function only works after refreshing the entire Wix page to reload the iFrame and finally the header() function will work only when the cookie "IsWixUser" has been set to 1 in the past.

Could this just be a problem with Drupal? that line of code you see above is within the top of the index.php for Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you cannot redirect a browser using the Location header once any other headers( i.e. cookies ) have been sent down. Remove the cookie setting line, and you'll be redirected.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the answer to your problem, but if you are sure you're doing everything right, try and use the `headers_sent`function of PHP. If not, it would at least give you an idea about what's going on.

For example:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
  //exit;
}
```

Try and feed the entire URL to the `Location`, like `http://....`. Drupal works in funny ways and one of these two things might just help.